# Does Apache pass a malformed HEAD request to PHP?

Tags: php, apache, apache2, php-5.3, apache2.2

Please consider the below request from apache access log.

```
119.63.193.131 - - [03/Oct/2013:19:22:19 +0000] "HEAD /blah/blahblah/ HTTP/1.1" 301 - "-" "\"Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1)\""
```

Does this request comply with the RFC / standard?

Would Apache pass malformed HEAD requests to PHP?

My configuration is Apache 2.2.15, mod_fcgid 2.3.7, PHP 5.3.3, Linux 2.6.32.60-40 x64, CentOS 6.4

Comment: Easy enough to test... telnet to port 80, hack up a head malformed head request on a php script, and see if php kicks in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see nothing obviously wrong about the request in that log entry. It has an unusual user agent (with double quotes in it), but that doesn't make it malformed - it's perfectly valid, and Apache would certainly pass it on to PHP.

Comment: Would it pass IF it was malformed? Thanks!

Comment: That would depend entirely on what was wrong with the request. Some malformations will be silently corrected, others will result in an automatic error response.

Comment: Do I understand you correctly: either PHP will see a proper request OR nothing at all ?

Comment: Is it an option for you to fix the client if you can identify what is wrong with the request? If it is, use wireshark, either on the server or on the client to capture the traffic, and then identify what is wrong with the request format. It might help if you can post here, either the HTTP conversation from the wireshark capture or the verbose log from the curl option I mentioned in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I have done fair few RESTful APIs with PHP and apache; never came across any such issues. Best would be to isolate the part that you want to doubly make sure to be working, which in your case is PHP and apache. So put together a basic PHP script that would dump `$_SERVER` and [apache_request_headers()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.apache-request-headers.php) (may be other global variables) which would give you enough clue as to whether it is working or not. use `curl -I` option for a command line HTTP client; you may also use `-v` option to see exactly what happens from the client's perspective.